# Select Query doesnt work on ajax file

Tags: php, mysql, ajax

```
$('select[name="third_category"]').change(function() {
        var first_cat = $('#main_category').val();
        var second_cat = $('#top_category').val();
        var third_cat = $(this).val();
        $.ajax({
            type:'POST',
            url:'ajax/fields_ajax.php',
            data:{'first_cat':first_cat, 'second_cat':second_cat, 'third_cat':third_cat},
            success:function(data){
                var field_box = document.getElementsByClassName('field_box');
                $(field_box).append(data);
            }
        });
    });
```

My goal is, when user select third option i collect all the option's values on the page. Then i'm going to use them for my mysql queries. That is my fields_ajax.php file.

```
<?php 
session_start();
ob_start();
include 'inc/session.php';
include 'inc/config.php';
include 'inc/mysql.class.php'; 
ini_set('display_errors', 0);

if( isset($_POST) ){ // secure script, works only if POST was made
    $first_cat   = $_POST[first_cat];
    $second_cat   = $_POST[second_cat];
    $third_cat   = $_POST[third_cat];

    $category_field_query = "SELECT * FROM categories WHERE id = $first_cat";
    $category_field_query_run = mysqli_query($connect, $category_field_query);
    $cat_field = mysqli_fetch_object($category_field_query_run);

    echo "<p>".$cat_field->fields."</p>";


 } ?>
```

I can carry all values without problem. But when i use them on query, there's no response. Mysqli connection working correctly, my query works on other php files. And when I try something else instead of trying mysql query, ajax file response it without problem.

Comment: Separate your concerns.  Diagnose your PHP script first, if that returns what you expect, then look at your AJAX request.

Comment: `$(field_box).append(data);`, the jQuery function takes a css selector, a DOM node or html string as an argument, `field_box` is neither of these

Comment: @Devon PHP script works correctly on other php files. Also ajax request works correctly too. When i echo first_cat inside fields_ajax.php it returns correct value.

Comment: Just so you know, your query is not secure.  Are you `ob_start()`ing for a reason?  I don't like your jquery selector after success.  Does that work?

Comment: How many field_boxes are there?

Comment: `mysqli_fetch_object($que_run);` Shouldn't this be `mysqli_fetch_object($category_field_query_run);`?

Comment: @mickmackusa Three. When user select first option, it triggers another ajax file which return related second select-box. And second one triggers last one. And last select-option changed, my query suppose to work.

Comment: Can we see the form / dom?

Comment: @DimitrisFilippou Yepp, changed. Thanks for warning. But the problem is still going on :/

Comment: Your SELECT uses `*` but you are only using a column called `fields`?  Just so you know `isset($_POST)` will ALWAYS be `true`.  You should quote your SUPERGLOBAL keys to avoid `constant` Warnings.

Comment: @mickmackusa Noted. Thanks for advices. Form and main scripts. https://codepen.io/Zasetsu/pen/WyLZqV  cat2_list.php which works after first select. https://codepen.io/Zasetsu/pen/eKbeYd  And cat3_list.php which works after second select. https://codepen.io/Zasetsu/pen/MXZOWy

Comment: Return your imploded $_POST array to confirm reception.  Then write some conditionals to check for syntax/logic errors in your query.

Comment: So there is only one `field_box` then. Does the categories table contain a `fields` column?

Comment: Definitely quote your keys in ALL of your scripts.  https://3v4l.org/HcIkt

Comment: @mickmackusa It does. As i said, when i run same query on different php file it works :/

Comment: There arent many more places to look now.  Echo the POSTed values.   Echo mysqli_error.  Echo your rendered query string.  I would be writing: `$('.field_box').append(data);`

Comment: I second `$('.field_box').append(data);` ... because if you are using jquery... use it to its advantages and ditch the longhand javascript selects ;)

Comment: @IncredibleHat do you know if the OP's selector can work?  I've never seen it done like that (and never would have thought to try).

Comment: @mickmackusa it works, sorta... jquery will take that sort of element group object to work on... but its really kinda janky. By wrapping the group in `$()` ... it puts jquery's methods on it, so you can do things like `.append`. Whereas doing `field_box.append` would NOT work, since it was not wrapped in jquery. However if made as `var field_box = $('.field_box);` ... then you COULD do `field_box.append`. LOL!

Comment: Well, then I guess the issue is in the POSTed variables because the connection and query works elsewhere. We will either need confirmation of the php page receiving the expected data or new details from the error log, or I'm just about ready to close as: Unclear / Typo, can't reproduce / Why isn't my code working

Comment: @mickmackusa There's no error from mysqli_error. Also I echoed posted values. All of them are correct. And rendered query string is SELECT fields FROM categories WHERE id = 1 for $_POST["first_cat"] = 1.

Comment: Can you use `console.log(data);`?

Comment: @mickmackusa It returns empty, not undefined.

Comment: Try another column that will be returned from `SELECT *`.  Try `id` column

Comment: What about isolating the object syntax with spaces or curly brackets? `"<p>". $cat_field->fields ."</p>"` or `"<p>{$cat_field->fields}</p>"`?

Comment: @mickmackusa Same, nothing. This time i tried to echo "<p>".$cat_field->fields."</p>". Ajax returns just p tags inside field_box correcty. And same for console log, only p tags. I cant get anything from database :/ I tried same method for id column.

Comment: Time to swap in another resultset function.  http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-assoc.php

Comment: Or http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.num-rows.php

Comment: You have posted: `ini_set('display_errors', 0);` but we dont want to silence errors right now.

Comment: @mickmackusa Deleted that line. And i tried other resultset functions. Still nothing. Its like it doesnt even try to fetch any data.

Comment: There must be an anomaly in your code that is not represented in your question.  Please provide an untouched copy-paste of your best/latest script that includes echoing checkpoints and mysqli_ error checking conditions.

Comment: Here's a general reference for checking for mysqli errors while using prepared statements with placeholders for security reasons: https://stackoverflow.com/a/43246696/2943403